# Extend Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter

Tags: magento-1.9, class, extend

I am trying to extend **`Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter`** class to add translate directive but I can't make it work.

Here my module:

> app/code/local/Company/Module/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_Module>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Company_Module>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <core>
                <rewrite>
                    <email_template_filter>Company_Module_Model_Email_Template_Filter</email_template_filter>
                </rewrite>
            </core>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Company/Module/Email/Template/Filter.php

```
<?php

class Company_Module_Model_Email_Template_Filter extends Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter
{
    public function translateDirective($construction)
    {
        $params = $this->_getIncludeParameters($construction[2]);
        $text = $params['text'];
            return Mage::helper('page')->__($text);
    } 

}
```

I can't figure it out why doesn't it work.
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution at the following link:
http://forum.azmagento.com/how-to/how-to-overload-mage_core_model_email_template_filter-37575.html

> You should overload Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter instead.
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <config>
>   <modules>
>     <MyPackage_CorePatches>
>       <version>0.1.0</version>
>     </MyPackage_CorePatches>
>   </modules>
>   <global>
>     <models>
>       <widget>
>         <rewrite>
>           <template_filter>MyPackage_CorePatches_Model_Template_Filter</template_filter>
>         </rewrite>
>       </widget>
>     </models>
>   </global>
> </config>
> ```
>
> This is because
>  class Mage_Widget_Model_Template_Filter extends
>   Mage_Cms_Model_Template_Filter{}
>  which in turn
>  class
>   Mage_Cms_Model_Template_Filter extends
>   Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter{}

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your `config.xml` you must replace:

```
Company_Modul_Model_Email_Template_Filter
```

With:

```
Company_Module_Model_Email_Template_Filter
```

Comment: thanks, but the typo is not in the real module :-)

Comment: @krybbio module is enabled ? Cache refreshed ? What is the result of `get_class(Mage::getModel('core/email_template_filter'));` ?